# "Least frequently used"  - algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am building an application that is supposed to extract a mission for the user from a finite mission pool. The thing is that I want:

1. that the user won't get the same mission twice,
2. that the user won't get the same missions as his friends (in the application) until some time has passed.

To summarize my problem, I need to extract the **least common mission** out of the pool.

Can someone please reference me to known algorithms of finding least common something (LFU).
I also need the theoretical aspect, so if someone knows some articles or research papers about this (from known magazines like Scientific American) that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

For getting the least frequently used mission, simply give every mission a counter that counts how many times it was used. Then search for the mission with the lowest counter value.

For getting the mission that was least frequently used by a group of friends, you can store for every user the missions he/she has done (and the number of times). This information is probably useful anyway. Then when a new mission needs to be chosen for a user, a (temporary) combined list of used missions and their frequencies by the users and all his friends can easily be created and sorted by frequency. This is not very expensive.

Comment: It wont work for me because each user has its own list of friends, so If some friends of user A doing mission X, it doesn't mean that user B cannot take this mission (because his friends are not touching mission X). So, Global counter wont work. There is a possibility of private counters, per user but it is just too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your 2 requirements, I don't see what "LEAST" used mission has anything to do with this. You said you want non repeating missions.

**OPTION 1:**
What container do you use to hold all missions? Assume it's a list, when you or your friend chooses a mission move that mission to the end of the list (swap it with the missions there). Now you have split your initial list into 2 sublists. The first part holds unused missions, and the second part holds used missions. Keep track of the pivot/index which separates the 2 lists.
Now every time you or your friends choose a new mission it is choosen it from the first sublist. Then move it into the second sublist and update the pivot.

**OPTION 2:**
If you repeat missions eventually, but choose first the ones which have been chosen the least amount of time, then you can make your container a min heap. Add a usage counter to each mission and add them to the heap based on that. Extract a mission and increment its usage counter then put it back into the heap. This is a good solution, but depending on how simple your program is, you could even use a circular buffer.

It would be nice to know more about what you're building :)

Answer (score 0):

A good start is Edmond Blossom V algorithm for a perfect minimum matching in general graph. If you have a bipartite graph you can look for the Floyd-Warshall algorithmus to find the shortest path. Maybe you can use also a topological search but I don't know because these algorithm are really hard to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure you need is a [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). It allows extraction of the minimum in O(Log(n)) and it allows you to increase the value of an item in O(Log(n)) too.